# Efficient Data Analysis and Visualization Techniques using PySpark and MongoDB

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

So I have ingested data to mongodb and I was able to view it using spark
I was able to  to read the data and confirm its there in mongo db

```
`%python
findspark.init()
import pyspark
import pandas as pd
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Hai Data Analysis').getOrCreate()
pydf_haidata =spark.read.format("mongo").option("uri","mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/dbv.ic1").load()
pydf_haidata.printSchema()`
```

Now I'm trying to visualize it using histogram loops etc on the data with pyspark and python codes as follows how do I do that and I m getting errors any suggestions

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=2, dpi=80, figsize=(11,8))
for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
   data = pydf_haidata[pydf_haidata.columns[i]]
   ax.plot(data, color='red', linewidth=1)
   ax.set_title(pydf_haidata.columns[i])
   ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
   ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
   ax.spines["top"].set_alpha(0)
   ax.tick_params(labelsize=7)
plt.tight_layout();
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=2, dpi=80, figsize=(11,8))
for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
   data = pydf_haidata[pydf_haidata.columns[i+8]]
   ax.plot(data, color='red', linewidth=1)
   ax.set_title(pydf_haidata.columns[i+8])
   ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
   ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
   ax.spines["top"].set_alpha(0)
   ax.tick_params(labelsize=7)
plt.tight_layout();
```

I have tried to use pandas to read the data from  pydf_haidata